# Solidity Mapping Iteration

Tags: blockchain, solidity

i'm new with solidity and i'm currently struggling iterating through a mapping index to get the values from a Struct

```
struct Stakes {
    uint256 stakeDate;
    uint256 stakeAmount;
}

mapping (address => Stakes[]) public addressToStaked;


function stake (uint256 _amount) public {
require(_amount > 0, "You must stake more than 0");
addressToStaked[msg.sender].push(Stakes(block.timestamp, _amount)); 
}

function returnStaked () public view returns (uint256[][] memory) {
uint256[][] memory result;
for (uint256 i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    result[i] = [addressToStaked[msg.sender][i].stakeDate, addressToStaked[msg.sender][i].stakeAmount];
}
return result;
}
```

As shown on the code, i'm able to push the Struct Values into the mapping, but when i try to read the values as in the returnStaked function i get the error:

TypeError: Type uint256[2] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think you can't iterate through mapping to get values.. if you want to get the stake for the particular address .. below code will work..

```
function returnStaked (address addressStaked) public view returns (Stakes[] memory) {
   return addressToStaked[addressStaked];
}
```

I will list some links for your references and if i found the way to do it.. i will update here...

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/iterable-mapping/

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/can-we-get-all-elements-stored-in-a-mapping-in-the-contract

https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/